# Vue.js - lodash | How to import only specific functions globally?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, lodash

I currently import the whole lodash library like this:

```js
import _ from 'lodash';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$_', { value: _ });
```

And it works fine, and I can access all the lodash functions using `this.$_.startCase()`

But I only use the function `startCase` and `omit` in my entire project. So I tried importing jus those functions:

```js
import {startCase, omit} from 'lodash/core';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$omit', { value: omit});
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$startCase', { value: omit});
```

But When I try to access these functions using `this.$omit()` it throws an error saying that function is not defined.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

In order to use named imports like `import {omit} from 'lodash/core'`, `lodash/core` should be ES module that has `export` statement for `omit`. `lodash` package is UMD, this means that it's treated as CommonJS module by Webpack and has only default exports due to module interoperability.

`lodash/core` works the same way as `lodash` in this regard, the whole module will be imported to the bundle:

```
import _ from 'lodash/core';
let { omit } = _;
```

Functions should be either imported from separate nested `lodash` modules:

```
import omit from 'lodash/omit';
```

Or they should be imported from `lodash-es` package that provides ES modules and allows named imports:

```
import {omit} from 'lodash-es';
```

Comment: The answer using the "lodash-es" module is exactly what you are wanting to do. I am using it in multiple Vue.js projects and it works amazingly.